# Which close price (adjusted close or close price) shall be used when calculating a stock's daily percent change?

Tags: stocks

Which close price (adjusted close or close price) shall be used when calculating a stock's daily percent change?

I've searched online everywhere but very disappointed that nothing was found. But I really want to know. Thanks!

For example: a stock had close price of $9.00 and adj. close price of $9.10, and the current price is $10.00, would it be showing (10 - 9)/9 = +%11.11 or (10 - 9.1)/9.1 = +%9.89?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adjusted close price takes into account stock splits (and possibly dividends). You want to look at the adjusted close price. Calculating percentage changes gets computationally tricky because you need to account for splits and dividends.